# Eclipse link 2.5.2 sometimes misses namespace prefix

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, eclipselink

Eclipse link 2.5.2 sometimes misses namespace prefix

I have a class generated from wsdl and it worked fine a long time till I switched to Weblogic 12.1.3 which uses EclipseLink 2.5.2 for marshalling objects.
It sometimes misses the namespave prefix on nodes in XML files after marshalling objects to XML which is a problem for other party webservice. 
Evrything works fine on EclipseLink 2.5.0 and Jaxb however I don't know whether I can switch to these libraries as WLS 12.1.3 uses 2.5.2 for some reason.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the old libraries, you just have to deploy your application with the old libraries and configure the weblogic.xml (in your deployment war) to prefer application libraries. Of course this would only be a workarround

Comment: so what would be to best solution?

Comment: The best solution would be if, if that bug gets fixed. But that unlikely to happen fast. I'll write something up what I mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

To replace an already existing jar, add the the one you want to use (in your case eclipselink 2.4.2) to your WEB-INF/lib Folder

Your WEB-INF/weblogic.xml file should look similiar to this, this will basically tell weblogic to prefer Classes from your deployment over its own.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.5/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.3</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>test</wls:context-root>

    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </wls:container-descriptor>

</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```